# Woocommerce cart session not expiring for logged in users

Tags: php, wordpress, session, woocommerce, cart

I have a woocommerce website. I need to exipre and remove cart items after a while. But the session not exipire for logged-in users.

I used the below code to achive this but its not working for logged in users:

```
add_filter('wc_session_expiring', 'filter_ExtendSessionExpiring');
add_filter('wc_session_expiration' , 'filter_ExtendSessionExpired');

function filter_ExtendSessionExpiring($seconds) {
    return 60*60*24;
}
function filter_ExtendSessionExpired($seconds) {
   return 60*60*25;
}
```

The above code works fine for non logged-in users, but I need it work for logged-in users too. Please advise

Comment: Did you ever solve this?

Answer (score 1):

This is because WooCommerce handles cart expiration differently for guests and logged-in users. Out of the box, **[the persistent cart](https://woocommerce.github.io/code-reference/files/woocommerce-includes-wc-cart-functions.html#source-view.48) feature is enabled for all logged-in customers** and allows them to keep the same cart contents even if they use different devices.

For this purpose, the plugin adds the `_woocommerce_persistent_cart_BLOG_ID` parameter containing all cart items to the user metadata (`wp_usermeta` table). You can disable this functionality by adding the following code:

```
add_filter('woocommerce_persistent_cart_enabled', '__return_false');
```

After that, your code would work well for all **new sessions** and force the cart to be emptied after expiration and running the `woocommerce_cleanup_sessions` cron job (by default, twice a day).